# Is there a way to keep the data when updating a database table using Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I have a working Laravel app, I needed to update a Model and add a new column to the database. In order to do this I added the following code to the database/migrations/table.php file:

```
Schema::table('client', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('newColumn');
});
```

When I try to update the database (with `php artisan migrate`) I get the message "Nothing to migrate". I noticed that the only way to apply this change is doing `php artisan migrate:refresh` or reset, but both commands drop every line on the database.

Is there anyway to update my database columns without dropping everything?

Comment: Do you have a migrations table? And did you create your migration using `php artisan make:migration add_newColumn_to_client`?

Comment: no, i created the the database migration table using make command but not to add the column, so thats the problem. i added the new field on the migrations file. thanks!

Comment: Right on, glad it was that easy!

Answer (score 3):

The complete solution The Maniac described would be:

- Create the new column with:`php artisan make:migration add_newColumn_to_client`.
- Add the following code to the newly created file (date_add_newColumn_to_client):

  ```
  public function up()
  {
      Schema::table('client', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->string('newColumn');
      });
  }
  ```
- run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

If you'll only add some column[s], you can export data with complete inserts statements, run migrate:refresh and re-import the data.  For MySQL:

```
mysqldump -u {USER} -p {DATABASE} --no-create-db --no-create-info --complete-insert > yourdata.sql
artisan migrate:refresh
mysql -u {USER} -p {DATABASE} < yourdata.sql
```